# Length of a PHP superglobal array

Tags: php, arrays, size

Is it possible to check how many items are within $_FILES[] using some sort of length() or size() ?

Answer (score 7):

It's a normal array besides the fact that it's superglobal - simply use [`count($_FILES)`](http://php.net/count).

To count the successfully uploaded files, you could do the following in PHP5.3:

```
$successCount = array_reduce($_FILES, function($val, $file) {
    if($file['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) return $val + 1;
    return $val;
}, 0);
```

In older PHP versions the easiest way (I consider string function names for callbacks ugly) would be using a simple loop:

```
$count = 0;
foreach($_FILES as $file) {
    if($file['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) $count++;
}
```

Comment: If I have 6 html input=files in a form then count($_FILES) returns 6 despite 3 of them not having any value. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @edwinNosh, I think you will have to loop through `$_FILES` and check how many of them have `UPLOAD_ERR_OK` as `$_FILES[$fieldName]['error']`. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php for more upload status codes and their descriptions.

Comment: Functional-programming-style approaches are "in" though. ;)

Comment: The "old PHP" version worked immediately, but I couldn't get the "new one" to work.  Then again, I'm a noobie. Thanks for posting this.

Answer (score 0):

The count() function does that: http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

`$c = count($_FILES);`

Comment: This statement counts all files, including null ones. If you need the number of uploaded files, use the ThiefMaster's good stuff above.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 ways in naming fields for the upload.
While `filename[]` will make this array messy, `filename1`, `filename2` etc will make $_FILES array behave as you expected and count($_FILES) will return number of input fields

If you don't know array structure, you should use `print_r($_FILES)` to see it first and then decide, what you want to count.

Also note that array name is `$_FILES`, not `$_FILES[]` as you mentioned. It's operator, not array name.

Comment: I believe edwinNosh is willing to know how many files are uploaded. See his question (and my answer) below ThiefMaster's answer.